# How many maps from $f: A \to A$ satisfy $f \circ f = f$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, function-and-relation-composition

I'm self-study working through a textbook intro to Category Theory. Suppose I have a set $A = \{1,2\}$, and I want to find how many maps $f: A \to A$ satisfy $f \circ f = f$.

I can enumerate the possible mappings $f: A \to A$ as pairs $(a,b)$ where $f(a) = b$:

1. $\{(1, 1), (2, 1)\}$
2. $\{(1, 1), (2, 2)\}$
3. $\{(1, 2), (2, 1)\}$
4. $\{(1, 2), (2, 2)\}$

For each of these four mappings, I can then run $f$ and $f \circ f$ to test if it satisfies $f \circ f = f$:

1. $\{1,2\} \to \{1,1\} \to \{1,1\}$. Works.
2. $\{1,2\} \to \{1,2\} \to \{1,2\}$. Works.
3. $\{1,2\} \to \{2,1\} \to \{1,2\}$. Works because $\{2,1\} = \{1,2\}$, order doesn't matter in sets.
4. $\{1,2\} \to \{2,2\} \to \{2,2\}$. Works.

Is this right? I don't know about my argument for the third mapping. Is it appropriate to say that $f \circ f = f$ because the resultant set is the same? Or do I actually have to map *each element* individually to the same element in order to claim $f \circ f = f$?

I suppose what I'm confused about is whether for $f \circ f = f$ to hold, I need $f \circ f = f$ for each *element* in $A$, or just for the overall set $A$.

Comment: For your example $3$, note we are not asking if $f(A)=f(f(A))$ with $A$ a set... we are asking if for each $a\in A$ whether we have $f(a)=f(f(a))$.  You have here $f(1)=2$ but $f(f(1))=f(2)=1$... so here we do *not* have $f(a)=f(f(a))$.

Comment: A for how to count... my first instinct is to break into cases based on how many *fixed points* there are... points for which $f(a)=a$.  There must be at least one, and as many as all of $A$.  Given a particular number of fixed points we can choose which points specifically are the fixed points.  All other points must map *to* a fixed point for $f\circ f = f$ to hold, so for each other point choose *which* fixed point from those we selected earlier they map to.  Maybe there is a convenient algebraic simplification hiding here, or a different combinatorial argument one can make.

Comment: "Order", more appropriately which element is sent to which, matters in evaluating any identity of functions $f=g$, and this instance is no exception.

Comment: I have removed the "category theory" tag. Even though the question may appear when studying category theory, the actual problem belongs to elementary set theory and combinatorics. No category theoretic notion has been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set of cardinal $n$.

A map $f:A\to A$ satisfies $f\circ f = f$ iif $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x\in A$, so iff $f(y) = y$ for all $y\in f(A)$. Thus, those points are fixed. One can still choose the images of the other points (as long as they are in $f(A)$).

Let's make a partition of all such $f$ by checking the cardinal of their images $f(A)$. This cardinal $k$ lies in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. We choose $k$ points among $n$, that is $\binom{n}{k}$ choices, for the elements of $f(A)$. If we note them $(y_1,\ldots,y_k)$, let's note $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-k})$ the remaining points. We must have $f(y_j) = y_j$ for $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$, so that is fixed, but we can choose $f(x_j)$ for $j\in\{1,\ldots,n-k\}$. It has to be in $f(A) = \{y_1,\ldots,y_k\}$, which makes for $k^{n-k}$ choices.

Thus, the number of map $f:A\to A$ such that $f\circ f = f$ is $$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k} k^{n-k}. $$

Comment: It looks prettier if you also included $k = 0$, since it doesn't change the answer here.

Comment: @GarethMa Also, if they include $k=0$ the formula is true for $n=0$ too, as opposed to being false.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Oh well, I mean it's technically undefined with $0^0$... Edge cases :" thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @GarethMa in the context of combinatorics, we always take $0^0$ to be defined to equal $1$.  Sure... there may be some other contexts out there where it is preferable to leave it as undefined, but not here.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah fair, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

For a finite set A with n elements, you can explicitly calculate the number of idempotent maps of A to itself.

**Hint.** Find a bijection between the set of idempotents and the pairs consisting of a subset T of A and a map from A\T to T.

**Hint 2.** Define T as the set of fixed points (=image) of an idempotent map.

If you want to know more (values, generating function, connection to other sequences), check out [OEIS/A000248](https://oeis.org/A000248).